# Removing a cursor in Sublime Text after Ctrl+click

Tags: sublimetext2

In Sublime Text, you can add a cursor to multiple arbitrary locations using Ctrl+click. However, using the mouse is often imprecise, so I sometimes encounter the need to undo a click (having already selected multiple locations in the text), but haven't found a way to do it so I have to start all over.

Is there a way to 'remove' a cursor after specifying it using the mouse?

Note: I'm aware of multiple cursor usage with the keyboard, this question is specifically about mouse usage.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `alt` modifier on windows and linux and `shift+cmd` modifier on OS X while selecting to use "subtractive" mode. You could also use a simple plugin to remove the first or last cursor in the view (not first or last added, first or last overall) and tie it to a key command.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. However, CTRL+U does.

Comment: Almost downvoted this as not working before finally figuring out what you're saying to do. You have to hold shift+cmd (or alt on non-Mac) and *drag a selection with the mouse that includes the cursors or selections you want to remove*. I was trying to hold shift+cmd and click on a cursor to make it vanish, which doesn't work; I suspect @Joncom above we made the same mistake. The answer could probably do with an edit to explicitly say what the user needs to do.

Comment: @MarkAmery how do you remove the first or last overall? I know how to add cursors at the bottom or top using select_lines but can you also remove cursors when using this? If so what is the argument passed to select lines as I can't find it.

Answer (score 18):

Don't mean to graveyard post on this subject, but I found this to be exactly what I was looking for:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> on Mac) seems to remove the last placed caret.

Found here: https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=5091

Digging through Sublime's Default Key Bindings files, the command name for this is `soft_undo`

So by modifying your user-defined key bindings, you can set any key/mouse combination you want to trigger `soft_undo`

Comment: Thanks for adding Mac variant @Mark Amery

Comment: I feel like this should be the selected answer

Answer (score 10):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Middle Click</kbd> works for Windows in Sublime3

Answer (score 2):

In case it helps:
If you are using the plugin `CodeIntel` (version 2.2.0), by removing it from Sublime, removing cursors with `alt+click` works again.